# quiero que un ciclo for guarde una N cantidad de clientes e imprima el total que han gastado

Tags: c

quiero que este ciclo for pueda almacenar la cantidad de clientes y ademas pueda darle descuentos segun la cantidad de dinero que se gaste el cliente para asi otorgarle un descuento del 30 por ciento si gasto mas de 500 pesos
como estoy empezando a programar en c, no se en que me estoy equivocando
ojala y me puedan ayudar 
gracias

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i=0,n;
float gc,ca;
int main(){
    printf("Escriba la cantidad de clientes");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if (n>i){
        for(i=1;i>0;i++){
        printf("Escriba el monto gastado por cliente");
            scanf("%f",gc);
        ca = (gc * .30);
        printf(" total a pagar: .2f%",ca);


        }
    }return 1;
}
```

Comment: gracias. algun tip que tengas para hacer el codigo?

Comment: Creo que deberías aclarar la pregunta, y seguramente recibiría mayor atención: `quiero que este ciclo for pueda almacenar...` ¿ Almacenar como ? ¿ Dónde ?

Comment: tu codigo tiene un monton de problemas. logicamente de solo mirarlo no solamente no hace lo que vos estas pidiendo que hagas, si no que ademas no termina nunca... podrias aclarar que estas buscando que haga exactamente?

Comment: lo que busco es ingresar una cantidad N de clientes y sus respectivos gastos y en base a lo que gastan aplicarles un descuento. por ejemplo :         a) Monto mayor o igual a $500, se hará un descuento del 30%
b) Monto menor de $500 pero mayor o igual a $200, se hará un descuento del 20%.
c) Monto menor de $200 pero mayor o igual a $100, se hará un descuento del 10%.
d) Monto menor a $100, no se realiza descuento.

Answer (score 0):

No he terminado de entender los motivos por los que @David ha borrado su respuesta. Coincido en prácticamente todo lo que ha dicho y en lo que no se lo he hecho saber (lo digo por si recapacita y decide revivir su respuesta).

> quiero que este ciclo for pueda almacenar la cantidad de clientes

La primera norma que deberías seguir es evitar el uso de variables globales... no te van a ayudar a programar mejor ni a entender mejor lo que estás haciendo.

Bien. Tu código para esta parte es este:

```
int main(){
    printf("Escriba la cantidad de clientes");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if (n>i){
        for(i=1;i>0;i++){
```

El cual es demasiado complicado para lo que tiene que hacer:

- Predir el número de clientes
- Para cada cliente hacer algo
- Si no hay clientes no hacer nada

Es decir:

```
int main(){
    int n;

    printf("Escriba la cantidad de clientes");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ // Iteramos en el rango 0..n
```

¿Y no hace falta el `if`? En absoluto. `for` ya tiene un condicional que permite abandonar el bucle y se evalúa desde la primera iteración. En el ejemplo que te he puesto, si `n==0` y `i==0`, entonces no se cumplirá `i<n` y no se ejecutará ninguna iteración.

> ademas pueda darle descuentos segun la cantidad de dinero que se gaste el cliente para asi otorgarle un descuento del 30 por ciento si gasto mas de 500 pesos

Tu código para esta parte es este:

```
printf("Escriba el monto gastado por cliente");
scanf("%f",gc);
ca = (gc * .30);
printf(" total a pagar: .2f%",ca);
```

Aquí estás aplicando el descuento **siempre**. Además el descuento que aplicas no es el 30% sino el 70%. `x*0.3` te da la cantidad a descontar y tu la estás usando como precio final.

Otro error que tienes es que estás configurando mal el último `printf`:

```
printf(" total a pagar: .2f%",ca);
//                         ^
```

Ese porcentaje tiene que estar al inicio del campo... no al final. El símbolo del porcentaje es lo que usa `printf` para saber que ahí empieza una sustitución.

La solución debería parcerse más a esta:

```
float gc = 0;
printf("Escriba el monto gastado por cliente");
scanf("%f",gc);
if( gc > 500.0 ) // Si se gasta más de 500 pesos...
  gc *= .7;      // ... se descuenta el 30% (100% - 30% = 70%)

printf(" total a pagar: %.2f", gc);
```

Nota que ahora la variable `gc` no existe. No sirve para nada. Solo tendría razón de ser si tuvieses que indicar en algun sitio el descuento aplicado:

```
float ga = 0, gc = 0;
printf("Escriba el monto gastado por cliente");
scanf("%f",gc);
if( gc > 500.0 ) // Si se gasta más de 500 pesos
  ga = gc * .3;  // Descuento del 50%

printf("A pagar: %.2f. Descuento: %.2f. Total %.2f", gc, ga, gc-ga);
```